# How to call a help method

Tags: java, graphics, panel

I have a homework assignment, where we're asked to write a helper method for a little graphics program. The problem I'm having is that it keeps saying I have an error.

> cannot find symbol - method drawPolygon(gp, int, int).

What am I missing?

PS. I know the GraphicsPanel code isn't in here, but was more wondering why I'd get the "cannot find symbol" error. When I write *just* drawPolygon(gp, 50, 4), it'll compile without any errors, but it won't draw anything in the panel either.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class G5 {
    public static void drawPolygon(GraphicsPanel gp, int sideCount, int sideLength) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            gp.draw(sideLength);
            gp.turn(360 / sideCount);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GraphicsPanel gp = new GraphicsPanel();
        gp.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        gp.delay(1000);
        int x = gp.getWidth() / 2;
        int y = gp.getHeight() / 2;
        gp.setLocation(x, y);

        gp.setColor(Color.RED);
        gp.drawPolygon(gp, 50, 4);

        gp.clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: [I removed the homework tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated). It should be clear from the question anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

The method is a static method of the G5 class. It's not an instance method of GraphicsPanel. So you must call it using

```
G5.drawPolygon(gp, 50, 4);
```

instead of

```
gp.drawPolygon(gp, 50, 4);
```

To be able to call it like you're doing, the method would have to be defined inside the GraphicsPanel class (or any of its superclass), without the static keyword.

Read [this section of the Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) to understand the difference between instance and static methods.

Comment: Oh!!! I got ya, duh!! >.< Thank you SOOOO much!!! edit(I compiled, it's fine, but it won't actually run, nothing happens in the graphics screen)

Comment: Static does not matter here. Please note that you CAN invoke a static method on an instance, it will just ignore the instance.

Comment: Of course it matters. If the method was not static, the OP would have to instantiate a new G5 in order to call the helper method. And calling static methods as instance method is a very, very bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

```
 gp.drawPolygon(gp, 50, 4);
```

You are looking for the method in the `GraphicsPanel` instance, not in your class. As it is an static method, use

```
G5.drawPolygon(gp, 50, 4);
```

instead